# Power BI :: Compare DATESMTD with previous month DATESMTD

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I created a MTD measure:

```
MTD = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Cost]),DATESMTD('Calendar'[Date].[Date]))
```

and a previous month MTD measure:

```
SPLM = CALCULATE([MTD], DATEADD('Calendar'[Date].[Date], -1, MONTH))
```

Following [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gw0t4TKkzE4).

The problem is that the line chart is acting weird and the two Cards that are supposed to show the numbers are `(Blank)` .

[image]

Here the:

- [.pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkcwioDIJzDoA4hiIJA?e=jwy7d2)
- [.xlsx](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkcwhkUIUR5Bz9ZjXcg?e=VVZarN)

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Just a quick response: 1. You follow the video but not exactly the measure (they do not use the date table as reference as you do), but this should not be an issue. What is the unexpected behavior? 2. Your cards are missing a date in order to calculate the measures, e.g. if you add a date slicer to your page and select a date, it should work (I reckon if you select a date in the line chart, the cards will work as well)

Comment: Well, the unexpected behavior is that in the video the line chart is comparing 2 months. In my screenshot is taking all the months from December till April. The cards don't need a date because they have to give me the total. Adding a slicer with the date didn't help

Comment: Did you try to click on a date in the line chart and see what happens with the cards?

Comment: I am not familiar using the date reference as you did in your measures. I usually use **calendar[date]**  I just changed that in your pbix and it works as expected. When you choose a date (within the range of your data) the cards will give you a value. Date can be from a slicer or from your line chart.

Comment: I think there is also a little misconception how visuals and measures work with each other. Your line chart shows the correct and expected result. I reckon in the video their data just covers those 2 months you see, that’s  all.

Comment: I don't want to use a slicer. I need the current MTD because this report need to be sent by e-mail automatically. That's how DATSMTD is supposed to work. I tried using `calendar[date]` and it didn't work

Comment: You meant to say/write it does not work as **you** expected. Again, it works as I described and explained above (as mentioned, I downloaded your pbix and tested it.) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to create a Month-to-Date (MTD) measure and a previous month MTD measure in Power BI, but the line chart is not behaving as expected and the two cards are showing `(Blank)`.

One possible reason for this issue could be that the data in the `Data[Cost]` column is not being recognized as a `numerical` value. You can try changing the `datatype` of the `Data[Cost]` column to a `numerical` value (e.g. `decimal number`) and see if that resolves the issue.

Another possible reason could be that there is an issue with the *relationship* between the `Data` and `Calendar` tables. You can check if there is an *active relationship* between these two tables and if the relationship is set up correctly.

Comment: You can download the pbix and check by yourself. The data type is decimal number and there is indeed a relation in the calendar